# ValueError in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, valueerror

I'm breaking my head here because of the following error. I checked this line of code several times:

```
import seaborn as sb     
sb.scatterplot(x="celsius", y="fahrenheit", datos=data)
```

which is giving me this error:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret value `celsius` for parameter `x`
```

I expected to generate a graph with markings of the X and Y values.

Comment: What do you mean "Syntax_error", when you are clearly getting a `ValueError`?

Comment: `datos=data` there is not `datos=` parameter. I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo / not reproducible. It's too localized.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), the parameters `x` and `y` must either be vectors, or keys by which to find vectors in the `data` parameter. `"celsius"` is not a vector, and you don't supply the `data` parameter (`sb.scatterplot` doesn't understand a parameter named `datos`), so `sb.scatterplot` doesn't know where to find the `x` values, and it is communicating this fact by throwing a `ValueError`.

Did you mean `data=data`, or `data=datos`, maybe?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer! In fact, I tried both with data=data and data=data (I followed a tutorial that was in Spanish and took care to write the codes faithfully). But it still follows this error, and when I changed the parameters to "X" and "Y" in uppercase, the graph was generated, but without the values ​​defined by the csv file.